# How to ignore multi columns in mybatis code generator?

Tags: ibatis, mybatis

Does anyone knows how to ignore multi columns in [mybatis code generation tool](http://www.mybatis.org/generator/)?
I know I can ignore one column with `<ignoreColumn>` elment, is there any method to ignore multi column at a time? 
For example: `<ignoreColumn column="col1, col2"/>` 
Any help is approciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use multiple `ignoreColumn` statements:

```
<ignoreColumn column="col1" />
<ignoreColumn column="col2" />
```